# WPF MVVM Combobox SelectedItem not working properly

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox, binding

I've already searched and read from several posts but I couldn't find what I am doing wrong.

I have a ComboBox with an `ObservableCollection<string> Available_COMPorts` as `ItemsSource`.
On `SelectedValue` I binded a string named `SelectedCOMPort` with `Mode = TwoWay`.

```
<Label Content="Porta COM: "></Label>
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Available_COMPorts}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedCOMPort, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

After bofere the combobox, I have a Label displaying the `SelectedCOMPort`

```
<Label Content="Status: " />
<Label Content="{Binding SelectedCOMPort}" Foreground="Red" />
```

I have made both `Available_COMPorts` and `SelectedCOMPort` with `INotifyPropertyChanged`. On my ViewModel Initialization, I filled the `Available_COMPorts` with the three SerialPort strings available ("COM6", "COM5", "COM4") and set `SelectedCOMPort = "Available_COMPorts[0]"` ("COM6").

When I Run the code, ComboBox has the three itens, the selected item is "COM6" and the label shows "COM6" (everything is fine). Then I select "COM5" and the label updates it's value to "COM5". This is presented on the following pictures.

[image: Image with SelectedCOMPort = "COM6", by default on ViewModel initialization]

[image: Image with SelectedCOMPort = "COM5", after selecting directly on the ComboBox]

The problem is when I try to access `SelectedCOMPort` on the `ViewModel`, as I need the selected item to connect on my SerialPort. The `SelectedCOMPort` is always as the default value "COM6". I try to access the `SelectedCOMPort`on the connect click command.

Debbuging, using Breakpoints on `INotifyProperty` functions I realized that the binding property seems to be working fine, but when it leaves `INotifyProperty` the value goes back to default.

Why is that happening? I've tryed several approachs and none worked for me.

Following is my ViewModel and BaseViewModel with INotifyProperty:

**BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged**

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region PropertyChange
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    protected void SetProperty<T>(ref T backingField, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingField, value)) return;
        backingField = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class LiveGraphViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ConnectButtonCommand ConnectButtonCommand { get; set; }
    private ObservableCollection<string> _availableCOMPorts;
    private string _selectedCOMPort;

    public ObservableCollection<string> Available_COMPorts
    {
        get { return _availableCOMPorts; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _availableCOMPorts, value); }
    }
    public string SelectedCOMPort
    {
        get {  return _selectedCOMPort; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _selectedCOMPort, value); }
    }
    public LiveGraphViewModel()
    {
        this.ConnectButtonCommand = new ConnectButtonCommand(this);
        ObservableCollection<string> TempCOM = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        foreach (string comport in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
            TempCOM.Add(comport);
        Available_COMPorts = TempCOM;
        if(Available_COMPorts.Count > 0)
            SelectedCOMPort = Available_COMPorts[0];
    }

    public void ConnectButton()
    {
        if (SelectedCOMPort == "COM5")
            Connect(SelectedCOMPort);
    }

}
```

**LiveGraphView XAML**

```
<UserControl x:Class="SmartAthleticsWPF.Views.LiveGraphView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SmartAthleticsWPF.Views" 
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:SmartAthleticsWPF.ViewModels"
             xmlns:commands="clr-namespace:SmartAthleticsWPF.Commands"
             xmlns:syncfusion="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Charts;assembly=Syncfusion.SfChart.WPF"
             xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <viewmodels:LiveGraphViewModel x:Key="LIVviewModel"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid Background="#EDEDED">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.01*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.01*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1.2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        
        <!--LIVE GRAPH BORDER-->
        <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Margin="5" 
                BorderBrush="Black" 
                BorderThickness="2" 
                CornerRadius="5"
                Padding="10,10,30,10"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

            <DockPanel>
                <Label Content="Live Graph" 
                       DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                       Padding="0,5,0,10" FontSize="22"/>

                <syncfusion:SfChart x:Name="LiveGraphChart" >
                    <syncfusion:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>
                        <syncfusion:NumericalAxis Header="Seconds" 
                                          Maximum="{Binding MaxXAxis}"
                                          Minimum="{Binding MinXAxis}"/>
                    </syncfusion:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>
                    <syncfusion:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>
                        <syncfusion:NumericalAxis Header="Kgf"/>
                    </syncfusion:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>

                    <syncfusion:SfChart.Series>
                        <syncfusion:FastLineBitmapSeries ItemsSource="{Binding FyCircularBuffer}" 
                                                         XBindingPath="XData" YBindingPath="YData" 
                                                         StrokeThickness="1" Interior="DarkGreen" 
                                                         ShowTooltip="False" ShowTrackballInfo="False" 
                                                         IsSeriesVisible="{Binding FyChecked}"/>
                        <syncfusion:FastLineBitmapSeries ItemsSource="{Binding MyCircularBuffer}" 
                                                         XBindingPath="XData" YBindingPath="YData" 
                                                         StrokeThickness="1" Interior="LimeGreen" 
                                                         ShowTooltip="False" ShowTrackballInfo="False" 
                                                         IsSeriesVisible="{Binding MyChecked}"/>
                        <syncfusion:FastLineBitmapSeries ItemsSource="{Binding FxCircularBuffer}" 
                                                         XBindingPath="XData" YBindingPath="YData" 
                                                         StrokeThickness="1" Interior="IndianRed" 
                                                         ShowTooltip="False" ShowTrackballInfo="False"
                                                         IsSeriesVisible="{Binding FxChecked}"/>
                        <syncfusion:FastLineBitmapSeries ItemsSource="{Binding MxCircularBuffer}" 
                                                         XBindingPath="XData" YBindingPath="YData" 
                                                         StrokeThickness="1" Interior="Red" 
                                                         ShowTooltip="False" ShowTrackballInfo="False"
                                                         IsSeriesVisible="{Binding MxChecked}"/>
                        <syncfusion:FastLineBitmapSeries ItemsSource="{Binding FzCircularBuffer}" 
                                                         XBindingPath="XData" YBindingPath="YData" 
                                                         StrokeThickness="1" Interior="BlueViolet" 
                                                         ShowTooltip="False" ShowTrackballInfo="False"
                                                         IsSeriesVisible="{Binding FzChecked}"/>
                        <syncfusion:FastLineBitmapSeries ItemsSource="{Binding MzCircularBuffer}" 
                                                         XBindingPath="XData" YBindingPath="YData" 
                                                         StrokeThickness="1" Interior="Blue" 
                                                         ShowTooltip="False" ShowTrackballInfo="False"
                                                         IsSeriesVisible="{Binding MzChecked}"/>
                    </syncfusion:SfChart.Series>

                </syncfusion:SfChart>
            </DockPanel>
        </Border>

        <!--COP BORDER-->
        <Border Grid.Row="2"
                Grid.Column="3"
                Margin="5" 
                BorderBrush="Black" 
                BorderThickness="2" 
                CornerRadius="5"
                Padding="10"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

            <DockPanel>

                <Label Content="C O P" 
                       Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                       DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="16"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       Padding="0,0,0,5"/>
                
                <syncfusion:SfChart x:Name="CopChart" 
                                    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    AreaBorderThickness="5"
                                    AreaBorderBrush="#523B97">
                    
                    <syncfusion:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>
                        <syncfusion:NumericalAxis Minimum="-20" 
                                                  Maximum="20" 
                                                  Interval="10" 
                                                  PlotOffset="5" 
                                                  BorderThickness="0" 
                                                  TickLineSize="0"
                                                  FontSize="12">
                            <syncfusion:NumericalAxis.AxisLineStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="Line">
                                    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="0"/>
                                </Style>
                            </syncfusion:NumericalAxis.AxisLineStyle>
                        </syncfusion:NumericalAxis>
                    </syncfusion:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>

                    <syncfusion:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>
                        <syncfusion:NumericalAxis Minimum="-30" 
                                                  Maximum="30" 
                                                  Interval="10" 
                                                  PlotOffset="5" 
                                                  BorderThickness="0" 
                                                  TickLineSize="0"
                                                  FontSize="12">
                            <syncfusion:NumericalAxis.AxisLineStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="Line">
                                    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="0"/>
                                </Style>
                            </syncfusion:NumericalAxis.AxisLineStyle>
                        </syncfusion:NumericalAxis>
                        
                    </syncfusion:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>

                    <syncfusion:SfChart.Annotations>
                        <syncfusion:LineAnnotation  X1="00"  X2="00"  Y1="-30" Y2="30"  
                                                    Stroke="DimGray" StrokeThickness="2" StrokeDashArray="4"/>
                        <syncfusion:LineAnnotation  X1="-20" X2="20"  Y1="00"  Y2="0"   
                                                    Stroke="DimGray" StrokeThickness="2" StrokeDashArray="4"/>
                    </syncfusion:SfChart.Annotations>
                    <syncfusion:SfChart.Series>
                        <syncfusion:FastScatterBitmapSeries ItemsSource="{Binding COP_DOT}" 
                                                  XBindingPath="XData" YBindingPath="YData" 
                                                  Interior="Red" ScatterHeight="20" ScatterWidth="20"/>
                    </syncfusion:SfChart.Series>

                </syncfusion:SfChart>

            </DockPanel>

            
        </Border>

        <!--SERIAL BORDER-->
        <Border Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="3"
                Margin="5" 
                BorderBrush="Black" 
                BorderThickness="2" 
                CornerRadius="5"
                Padding="15,0,15,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                
                <Label Content="Conexão" 
                       Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                       DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="16"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       Padding="0,0,0,5"/>

                <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" LastChildFill="True">
                    <Label Content="Porta COM: "></Label>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Available_COMPorts}"
                              SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedCOMPort, Mode=TwoWay}"
                              Margin="0,0,0,15"   />

                    <!--SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCOMPort, Mode=TwoWay, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"-->
                </DockPanel>

                <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Connect/Disconnect" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5"
                        Command="{Binding Path=ConnectButtonCommand, Source={StaticResource LIVviewModel}}"/>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <Label Content="Status: "></Label>
                    <Label Content="{Binding SelectedCOMPort}" Foreground="Red" />
                </StackPanel>


            </Grid>
        </Border>

        <Grid Grid.Row="3"
              Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            
            <!--SERIAL BORDER-->
            <Border Grid.Column="0" 
                    Margin="5" 
                    BorderBrush="Black" 
                    BorderThickness="2"
                    CornerRadius="5"
                    Padding="20,0,20,0">

            </Border>
            
            <!--RECORD BORDER-->
            <Border Grid.Column="1" 
                    Margin="5" 
                    BorderBrush="Black" 
                    BorderThickness="2"
                    CornerRadius="5"
                    Padding="20,0,20,0">

                <Grid Margin="5,10,5,10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1.5*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,0,10"
                            Content="Click me" Command="{Binding Path=RecordButtonCommand, Source={StaticResource LIVviewModel}}" />

                    <Label Content="Record Time (s):" 
                           Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="30" Background="White" 
                               Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                    <Label Content="Name:" 
                           Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Subject Name" 
                           Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                </Grid>
            </Border>
            
            
            <!--Informações do Gráfico BORDER-->
            <Border Grid.Column="2" 
                    Margin="5" 
                    BorderBrush="Black" 
                    BorderThickness="2"
                    CornerRadius="5"
                    Padding="10,0,10,0">

                <Grid>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    
                    <Label Content="Informações do Gráfico" 
                           Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" />

                    <CheckBox Content="Fy" 
                              Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" 
                              FontWeight="ExtraBlack" FontSize="12"
                              Foreground="DarkGreen"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              IsChecked="{Binding FyChecked}" />
                    <CheckBox Content="My" 
                              Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
                              FontWeight="ExtraBlack" FontSize="12"
                              Foreground="LimeGreen"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              IsChecked="{Binding MyChecked}" />
                    <CheckBox Content="Fx" 
                              Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"
                              FontWeight="ExtraBlack" FontSize="12"
                              Foreground="IndianRed"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              IsChecked="{Binding FxChecked}" />
                    <CheckBox Content="Mx" 
                              Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1"
                              FontWeight="ExtraBlack" FontSize="12"
                              Foreground="Red"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              IsChecked="{Binding MxChecked}" />
                    <CheckBox Content="Fz" 
                              Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1"
                              FontWeight="ExtraBlack" FontSize="12"
                              Foreground="BlueViolet"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              IsChecked="{Binding FzChecked}" />
                    <CheckBox Content="Mz" 
                              Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="1"
                              FontWeight="ExtraBlack" FontSize="12"
                              Foreground="Blue"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              IsChecked="{Binding MzChecked}" />

                    <DockPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" LastChildFill="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Label Content="Periodo: "  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <ComboBox Text="30" Background="White"  VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                  SelectedIndex="{Binding PeriodSelectedIndex}"> <!--5-->
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="100 ms" />
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="500 ms" />
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="1 s" />
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="5 s" />
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="10 s" />
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="30 s" />
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DockPanel>

                    <DockPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" LastChildFill="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Label Content="Amplitude: " VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <ComboBox Text="30" Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                  SelectedIndex="{Binding AmplitudeSelectedIndex}"> <!--3-->
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="10"/>
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="100"/>
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="500"/>
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="1000"/>
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="5000"/>
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="10000"/>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DockPanel>

                    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Content="{Binding PesoKg}" ContentStringFormat="Peso (kg): {0}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

                    <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Content="{Binding PesoNw}" ContentStringFormat="Força (N): {0}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    
                </Grid>

            </Border>

        </Grid>

        


    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Connect Button**

```
    public class ConnectButtonCommand : ICommand
    {
        public LiveGraphViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
        public ConnectButtonCommand(LiveGraphViewModel viewModel)
        {
            this.ViewModel = viewModel;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            this.ViewModel.ConnectButton();
        }
    }
```

**DataContext**

```
public partial class LiveGraphView : UserControl 
{
    private LiveGraphViewModel _vm;
    public LiveGraphView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this._vm = new LiveGraphViewModel();
        this.DataContext = this._vm;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Where is the part where you want to connect/use the selected value?

Comment: You write "*The problem is when I try to access SelectedCOMPort on the ViewModel*" but you don't show us that code. It seems likely that you are trying to acces a different instance of the view model, since the one in your UserControl is private to the UserControl and not accessible from the outside. In general, UserControls should not have private view models, but instead expose bindable properties that are bound to properties of a view model object that is provided by their inherited, parent DataContext.

Comment: As a note, unless you set SelectedValuePath, you would not bind SelectedValue, but SelectedItem instead.

Comment: @SirRufo I eddited the post to show where I try to acess the selected value.
I try to use it when i Click on the Connect Button.

Comment: Where is the ConnectButton method called?

Comment: @Clemens I do not change my UserControl. The code is too huge to show it complete here. Everything is on the LiveGraphViewlModel. I'll add a picture of the whole program, the UserControl is everything on the midle of the program (white background) is my UserControl Content

Comment: I also didn't show the ConnectButton method because it is working. The function `public void ConnectButton()` is working, the problem is on the SelectedItem value that don't change. If you want I can share the whole code on github here.

Comment: You mean SelectedCOMPort isn't changing? There is no SelectedItem in your code. If you are positively sure there is only a single view model instance involved, all you are showing here should work. The problem is somewhere else. Showing a screenshot of your UI doesn't help at all.

Comment: @Clemens yes, the SelectedCOMPort don't change but it changes the label (with red foreground) on the UI.

Comment: The changing Label Content proves that SelectedCOMPort changes on the DataContext, i.e. the view model instance of the UserControl. For the ConnectButton method, we have no idea how or where it is called. We can't help you without seeing more details, sorry.

Comment: @Clemens I added the ConnectButton method. 

It goes inside the ConnectButton function, and there I try to acess SelectedCOMPort, but it always has the initial value.

Comment: https://github.com/eduhza/SmartAthleticsWPF
@Clemens

Comment: As I said, you have two view model instances, one created in the  UserControl's constructor, one created in its Resources. The command operates on the latter, which is of course wrong. The Command property of the Button should be bound to the command property of the view model instance in the DataContext, not to the XAML resource.

Comment: @Clemens you are precisely right! 
Removed the UserControl.Resources on the XAML and now is working perfecly.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Clemens I had two view model instances at the same time.
One created in the UserControl's constructor (code behind) and other on the XAML Resources.

So, I removed the last one and everything works fine.

```
<!--
<UserControl.Resources>
    <viewmodels:LiveGraphViewModel x:Key="LIVviewModel"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
-->

<Label Content="Porta COM: "></Label>
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Available_COMPorts}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedCOMPort, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<Button Content="Connect/Disconnect" 
        Command="{Binding Path=ConnectButtonCommand}" />
```